# Numeração única no data frame

Tags: r

Tenho uma base de dados que contem informacao de consumo por animal e por dia. Contudo os animais entraram em dias diferentes no experimento.
Inicialmente preciso fazer com que todos animais comecem a contagem dos dias em experimento a partir de 1. Segue parte da base

```
Animal  Dia Consumo
5       9   2533.96
5       10  2329.06
5       11  2943.79
5       12  3361.62
5       13  2890.82
5       14  2538.98
5       15  2978.81
5       16  3038.76
5       17  3038.76
6       10  2314.82
6       11  2434.75
6       12  2643.99
6       13  2320.58
6       14  2439.56
6       15  2139.6
6       16  2459.54
6       17  2339.59
```

Após essa numeração unica para todos os animais preciso calcular o consumo médio e desvio padrão de todos os animais a cada dia.

Comment: Já experimentou alguma coisa? O quê? Coloque aqui o seu código

Comment: Deixe ver se percebi: o animal 5 começa o experimento no dia 9, o animal 6 no dia 10. Então, esse dia passa a ser o dia 1 da contagem? Se sim, para calcular a média e o desvio padrão, pretende essas estatísticas para o dia 1 da contagem de cada animal, para o dia 2 da contagem, etc? O resultado da média para o dia 1 será então `(2533.96 + 2314.82)/2 == 2424.390`. Isto está certo?

Comment: Sim, é isso mesmo

Comment: Eu até sei como calcular a média e desvio, só precisaria faer com cada animal inicie sempre em 1. Por exemplo oa animal 5 seria 1 ao inves de 9.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para resolver o problema vou usar a estratégia de [split-apply-combine](https://www.jstatsoft.org/article/view/v040i01) várias vezes, com uma única instrução de cada vez.

Em primeiro lugar, criamos a coluna `Contagem` com a função `ave`.

```
dados$Contagem <- ave(dados$Dia, dados$Animal, FUN = function(x) x - x[1] + 1)
```

De seguida calculam-se a média e o desvio padrão com `tapply`.

```
tapply(dados$Consumo, dados$Contagem, mean)
tapply(dados$Consumo, dados$Contagem, sd)
```

Também se podem criar novas colunas na `data.frame` com estas estatísticas, para isso usa-se mais uma vez a função `ave`. Isto porque apesar de tanto `ave` como `tapply` fazerem os mesmos cálculos a função `tapply` retorna um só valor por grupo enquanto que o `ave` retorna um valor por linha da base. (Os valores são iguais e no caso de `ave` repetem-se em todas as linhas do mesmo grupo.)

```
dados$Media <- ave(dados$Consumo, dados$Contagem, FUN = mean)
dados$DesvioPadrao <- ave(dados$Consumo, dados$Contagem, FUN = sd)
```

**DADOS.**

```
dados <-
structure(list(Animal = c(5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L), Dia = c(9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 
14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L), 
    Consumo = c(2533.96, 2329.06, 2943.79, 3361.62, 2890.82, 
    2538.98, 2978.81, 3038.76, 3038.76, 2314.82, 2434.75, 2643.99, 
    2320.58, 2439.56, 2139.6, 2459.54, 2339.59)), .Names = c("Animal", 
"Dia", "Consumo"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -17L
))
```